# Linux - Feed a command input with a file and delete the file while the command is running

Tags: linux, background-process, io-redirection

Could some one tell me a single line command to feed my cmd input from a file and delete the same file while the command is still running?

EDIT: By single line command I meant, performing this entire action in one command. This behavior has got to do with executing processes and commands simultaneously. Hence I would want to see what happens when the command line input is fed with a file and in the same command using the concept of simultaneous process execution (Read foreground and background) delete the file while the cmd input is still reading it

I tried

```
$ cat dummy_file.txt | rm -i
rm: missing operand
Try rm --help for more information
```

Obviously the cmd I tried is wrong. Maybe I need to run one of the command as background jobs but I'm not sure

Comment: define `single line command`.  Since *nix shells allow you to have multiple commands on one line, separated by a `;`, a `single line command` can do pretty much anything.

Comment: You want to read the contents of a file and delete it afterwards? What's your command? What have you tried? Please edit and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're actually trying to achieve; but your example command can be "fixed" in a way by using xargs:

```
echo "dummy_file.txt" > dummy_file.txt
cat dummy_file.txt | xargs rm -i
```

Btw. if you're worried about deleting a file while it is being used: while a file is in use (ie. kept open) by a process, its *contents* will not be deleted from disk. Even if you delete the file with `rm`, only the file name in the directory structure is removed; the disk space for the actual contents is only freed when the file is no longer kept open by any process.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for. To delete the file while its still being read by cmd-line. I tried `cat dummy_file.txt & rm dummy_file.txt` and that worked too.. Basically cat wasn't able to complete coz it couldn't find the file which got deleted while the `cat` was still running. Thanks for the additional info.